# Separate row selection from row checkbox selection?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Does ag-grid support separating row selection from checked checkboxes?

My users need to select a row (click on it, or keyboard nav) to see further details about the row. Then they need to check the checkbox (or not) to select the row for later export to Excel.

So for example, they'll click every row to see the further details, but only check some of the checkboxes for later export. Is this supported?

If not, what would be a good approach to implement? Add my own checkboxes to the first column?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `suppressRowClickSelection` to `true` when you want checkbox selection, and don't want to also select when the row is clicked. If true, rows won't be selected when clicked.

You can read more about this here - https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-selection/

Comment: I don't think your answer quite addresses my question. Setting `suppressRowClickSelection = true` stops a mouse click on a row from selecting (highlighting) the row. That's not what I'm asking.

I want to (1) click a row and have it be selected (highlighted), but not have the checkbox be checked, and (2) click a checkbox and have the checkbox checked, but the row not selected (highlighted)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ag-Grids selection capabilities for the checkbox selection and then use the `onRowClicked` prop to do a different select on row click. I'm doing just this (but with `onRowDoubleClicked`.

You still want to set `suppressRowClickSelection` to `true`.